# timestamp conversion, ISODate

Tags: timestamp, hana

i hope you can help me:

I have string: 2013-05-01T00:01:00Z  , which I believe it is in ISODate format. I would like to convert it to timestamp. Does anybody know how to do this?

I am using SAP HANA , but some links can be made with oracle dbs!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('2010-01-11 13:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') "to timestamp" FROM DUMMY;
```